# Why does the math library only need to be linked when used outside of main?

Tags: c, gcc, ld

Using `gcc test.c`, the first code sample compiles, while the second does not. Why?

They both work with explicit linking of the math library (i.e. `gcc test.c -lm`.

First Sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {
   printf("%lf\n", sqrt(4.0) );
   return 0;
}
```

Second Sample:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double sqrt2(double a) { return sqrt(a); }

int main() {
  printf("%lf\n", sqrt(4.0));
  printf("%lf\n", sqrt2(4.0));
  return 0;
}
```

Linker error with second sample:

```
/tmp/ccuYdso7.o: In function `sqrt2':
test.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

gcc -v:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-libmpx --with-system-zlib --with-isl --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libssp --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-install-libiberty --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-mul
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.1.0 (GCC)
```

There is no linker error for uses of `sqrt` in the main function. Is there any particular reason that this is the case?

I also checked with clang, but neither compiled (linker errors) without the `-lm`.

Comment: I would guess that it gets inlined in the first example so there is nothing to link.

Comment: Check the disassembly. I have a strong feeling `sqrt(4.0)` was optimized away.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

gcc is a *particularly* clever compiler.

It will optimise out `sqrt(4.0)` as a compile time evaluable constant expression. It can do that since the definition of `sqrt` is defined by the standard and its return value is solely a function of its input. (Note futher that under IEEE754, `sqrt` must return the closest `double` to the final result. This further supports the optimisation hypothesis.)

In the second case, the presence of  *function* (which could be used by other translation units) defeats this optimisation.

Answer (score 3):

Since the argument to `sqrt` is known at compile time, and its behaviour is standardised, `sqrt(4.0)` can be calculated at compile time.

Comment: If you don't mind, I added a phrase on the function being standardised.